# python работает некорректно в ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x

Пытался сделать python3 по умолчанию в ubuntu, выполнил команду: `sudo ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python`. Забыв про то, что многие большая часть программ написана на python2.7. Пытался сделать: `sudo ln -sf python2.7 /usr/bin/python`, что-то заработало, а что-то нет. К примеру модули установленные через pip работают ужасно

Comment: Что значит "работают ужасно"?

Comment: Не стоит заменять python на python3. Многие системные части и утилиты используют python2 и в случае подмены интерпретатора будут вылетать с ошибками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы выбиралась нужная версия интерпретатора, правильным решением будет указание её в первой строке `.py`-файла:

```
#/usr/bin/env python3
```

Answer (score -1):

Выполни: `sudo ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python` у меня после этого все заработало.

Comment: минус. не трогайте системный питон на убунте -- это хороший способ привести её в нерабочее состояние. Можете для себя (например, в `~/bin/`) создать `python` ссылку, которая указывает на желаемую версию, но `/usr/bin/python` не следует трогать (что apt туда положил, то и должно быть).